# Handlebars and Looping Through JSON Objects

Tags: json, mongodb, mongoose, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

Mind if I ask for some advice on how to loop through the follow JSON objects please and put it into a Handlebars template?

I've found a lot of similar questions here for "Handlebars and looping through JSON", but after quite a few hours of reading & trying various permuations, I'm pretty stuck.

The resorts object appears on the template page ok, if I print {{resorts}}.

And I can get a bullet list that seems to correspond with the number of documents within resorts.

But my goal is to get a bulleted list of each properties Name, and I've not been able to do that.

Many thanks in advance for any help.

**My JSON:**

```
{ properties: { 
      Country: 'United States', 
      Name: 'Killington', 
      description: `blurb` 
  }, 
  geometry: { 
      coordinates: [ -72.8032981, 43.6176027 ], 
      type: 'Point' 
    }, 
  datePosted: 2020-01-10T12:07:00.340Z, 
  _id: 5e11cd71746ed55b54a760ec, 
  type: 'Feature' 
},
{ properties: { 
      Country: 'United States', 
      Name: 'Jay', 
      description: `blurb` 
  }, 
  geometry: { 
      coordinates: [ -72.8032981, 43.6176027 ], 
      type: 'Point' 
    }, 
  datePosted: 2020-01-10T12:07:00.340Z, 
  _id: 5e11cd71746ed55b54a760ec, 
  type: 'Feature' 
}
```

**My MongoDB Model (resort.js)**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const ResortSchema = new Schema ({
  type: String,
  properties:{
    Country: String,
    Name: String,
    description: String
  },
  geometry: {
    type: {
      type: String, 
      enum: ['Point'],
      required: true
    },
    coordinates: {
      type: [Number],
      required: true
    }
  },
  datePosted: {
    type: Date,
    default: new Date()
  },
  image: String
})


const Resort = mongoose.model('Resort', ResortSchema);

module.exports = Resort
```

**My JS**

```
exports.home = async(req, res) => {
  const Resort = require('../models/resort')
  const resorts = await Resort.find({})
  res.render('home', {resorts: resorts})
}
```

**My Handlebars Template:**

```
{{#if resorts}}
<ul>
  {{#each resorts}}
  <li>
    {{properties.Name}}
  </li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
{{/if}}
```

**Edit:**
I get a JSON output if I do the following, but still can't succeed if I try to drill down to properties.Name:

```
<ul>
  {{#resorts}}
      <li>
        {{this}}
      </li>
  {{/resorts}}
</ul>
```

**Output**

```
{ properties: { Country: 'USA', Name: 'Killington', description: "blurb" }, geometry: { coordinates: [ -72.8032981, 43.6176027 ], type: 'Point' }, datePosted: 2020-01-10T12:07:00.340Z, _id: 5e11cd71746ed55b54a760ec, type: 'Feature' }
```

**UPDATE**

Currently trying to create JSON validation in MongoDB.  Could have something to do with that.

Comment: Have you tried using `this` as `{{this.properties.Name}}`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @chridam.  That gets me the bullets.  But unfortunately the name doesn't come through.  I was also unsuccessful with other similar variants, such as {{ this.Name}} or {{Name}}.

Answer (score -1):

```
<ul>
  {{#each resorts}}
    {{#each this}}
      <li>{{name}}</li>
    {{/each}}
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

or

```
<ul>
  {{#each resorts}}
    {{#each this}}
      <li>{{this.name}}</li>
    {{/each}}
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```